# Migration Error when I execute migration command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This error appear when I try to write this command:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MusicStoreContext
```

Comment: What visual studio version you're using?

Comment: version 2013 with update 4

Comment: According [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805933/filenotfoundexception-enabling-ef-migration) problem should be resolved since update 2. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell%2C+Version%3D10.0.0.0&oq=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell%2C+Version%3D10.0.0.0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) throws some other options, have you explored all?

Comment: I downloaded and setup Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package .. but still not working

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: The version of Framework is 4.0